Откуда скачать драйвера SQL для QT? Нужно ли для корректной работы скачивать БД?
В папке plugins Qt отсутствует папка sqldrivers со всеми драйверами SQL. Откуда скачать эту папка/как ее восстановить? Нужно ли для корректной работы с БД в проекте Qt скачивать саму БД на компьютер, если разворачиваешь ее в Docker? Версия qt 6.7.2. macOS.

Встраиваемые плагины/драйвера поставляются с исходным кодом. Так что самый простой способ - пересобрать из исходников (как задать при установке - смотрите в свой установщик, я собираю напрямую из исходников).
Но есть ньюанс ))) Я сам работаю с PostgreSQL и обратил внимание, что встраиваемые драйвера не обрабатывают сообщения об ошибках сервера. В частности при попытке выполнения запроса с синтаксической ошибкой никакой реакции не видно, оператор вроде выполняется, но ничего не получает и библиотека Qt никак не реагирует. Поэтому просто и тупо переписал доступ на штатные библиотеки PostgreSQL. Получилось немного замороченнее. Многие скажут - зря и невозможно использовать штатные средства Qt и наверное будут правы, но мне важен полный контроль над ошибками.

Интересное решение, почему бы нет)
